# Why the cosin of an acute angle in a right-angled triangle

Tags: trigonometry

That is (the cosin I mean), the abscissa of a generic point P along the circumference or the lenght of the perpendicular projection of P onto the ordinate, is given by the ratio of the adjacent cathetus to the hypotenus? The same question can be asked about the sinus obviously; is it something to be taken just as it is, as a matter of fact, a definition?

Comment: Yes, cosine is **defined** as the ratio of the adjacent side to the hypotenuse of a right angled triangle

Comment: Now also dig up the definitions of hypothenuse, triangle, right angle ...